# Is it possible to say that $L(f^n)=s^nL(f)$ when the differential equation is not in the rest condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

## Question

Use the Laplace transform to solve the following equation:
$y'+2y=\cos(3t)$ ; where $y(0)=1$

---

In class our teacher wrote that "When in rest condition: $L(f^n)=s^nL(f)$", but I want to use this on this problem even though the rest condition is not satisfied here.

Note - we were taught that the rest condition is when $$y^{(n-1)}(0)=0, y^{(n-2)}(0)=0,\ldots,y^{(0)}(0)=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general case we have: $$L(f^n)=s^nL(f)-s^{n-1}f(0)-\dots-sf^{n-2}(0)-f^{n-1}(0)$$
so $$L(y')=sL(y)-y(0)=sL(y)-1$$
then  $$sL(y)-1+2L(y)=\frac{s}{s^2+9}$$
$$L(y)=\frac{s^2+s+9}{(s+2)(s^2+9)}$$
$$L(y)=\frac{\frac{2}{13}s+\frac{9}{13}}{s^2+9}+\frac{\frac{11}{13}}{s+2}$$
$$L(y)=\frac{2}{13}\frac{s}{s^2+9}+\frac{9}{13}\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{s^2+9}+\frac{11}{13}\frac{1}{s+2}$$
$$y(t)=\frac{2}{13}\cos 3t+\frac{9}{39}\sin 3t+\frac{11}{13}e^{-2t}$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if we were also given the initial condition of $y'(0)=1$, would it then be $sL(y)-y(0)-y'(0)$? I'm just trying to fully grasp the general case you have written up there.

Comment: @DarthVoid if you are writing the equation for the first derivative then $y'(0)$ won't come in the equation even if it has a value like $1$ but if your differential equation is of order 2 and you are using the proposition for second derivative it will be $s^2L(y)-sy(0)-y'(0)$

Comment: Ok. Also, how did you get to the third to last line ($\frac{\frac{2}{13}s+\frac{9}{13}}{s^2+9}...$)? did you use partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Yes I decomposed the fraction

Comment: For the nominator of $s^2+9$ i thought of a polynomial of degree 1 like $as+b$ and for the nominator of $s+2$ i thought of a constant c then I found a and b and c.partial fraction decomposition

Comment: Yup. Just worked it out and I got the same coefficients you did. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The general formula is 
$$ L(f^{(n)})(s) = s^n L(f)(s) - \sum_{k=1}^n s^{n-k} f^{(k-1)}(0) $$

In particular, $L(y')(s) = s L(y)(s) - y(0)$.